# Get specific id in backend/db

Tags: angular

Currently I'm playing with params in Angular and I have a problem.
In my params I have an `id` like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/personen/pDetails/d6f2d07e-0b5a-4353-991c-0001a803981e
```

Now I got a database, which have entries like this, and I need the `personentypId`. The `id` in my parameters is already the `personId`.

```json
{
"personId":"d6f2d07e-0b5a-4353-991c-0001a803981e",
"personentypId":"1cf117e9-1064-4b17-bfe5-ed3a6621bf65", 
... 
}
```

My API link for this is:

```
"http://localhost:5000/api/Personentypzuordnungens"
```

There is a big list with thousands of ids, but i only need the correct personentypId to my personId.

I tried it like with a parameter for my api like that:

My Service:

```js
readonly zController = 'http://localhost:5000/api/Personentypzuordnungens/';

getUser(userid: string){
   console.log(this.zController + userid);
   return this.http.get<Zuordungsmodel[]>(this.zController + userid);
}
```

My Model:

```js
export interface Zuordungsmodel {
   personId: string;
   personTypId: string;        
}
```

My `component.ts`:

```js
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     const id = params['id'];
     this.zService
          .getTypeId(id)
          .subscribe(data => { this.person = data; })
});
```

With this I get the following [error](https://ibb.co/xhsxq58).

Means a problem in my backend in this code:

```js
public async Task<ActionResult<Personentypzuordnungen>> GetPersonentypzuordnungen(Guid id){
    var personentypzuordnungen = await _context.Personentypzuordnungens.FindAsync(id);

    if (personentypzuordnungen == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

return personentypzuordnungen;
}
```

It seems like he cant find the `id`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Nothing to do with Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by myself. Problem was in the backend.

```js
var personentypzuordnungen = await _context.Personentypzuordnungens
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.PersonId == id);
```

Fixed it.